# Uncountable Sets and an Infinite Real Number Game

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In Problem #1542 of Mathematics Magazine, Grossman and Turett define the Cantor game.
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606253
This is a "proof" of the real numbers being uncountable, that is supposedly "in many ways much simpler than Cantor’s original proof".

I can't even find one of the "many ways". I can't even see why it would be a proof at all.

Unfortunately there is not much information on the web about it. Even Mathematics Magazine does not have it. (may need a subscription to find it)

If anyone can give me a hint as to why this proof works, I would be very grateful.

Edit to make the question more clear:

If this is a correct summation of the proof then my problem follows.

We have a set $S = [0, 1] $, we will let the first element be $s_1$ where it's value will be derived from tossing an infinite number of coins. If the coins land HHTHHHTHHHHHHT $\dots$ then the binary value of $s_1 = 0.11011101111110 \dots$ we will repeat this for each element $s_n$ of the set $S$

Then Alice and Bob will choose their numbers so that $S_n ≤ a_n \lor S_n ≥ b_n$

Since $a_n < α_n < b_n$ for all $n$, we conclude that $α_n \notin S$

The idea of the proof is that if by some miraculous stroke of luck our coin toss gives us $α_n$ then we can just make a new $α_{n+1}$ and keep playing the game till we run out of coin tosses or the probability of the coin tosses producing the new $α_n$ actually becomes zero and not just approaches zero.

My problem is "what allows us to say that we will actually run out of coin tosses when we should have an endless amount of them and why would the probability of the coin toss being $α_n$ ever actually be zero?"

Comment: What is your question? You write as if you did not have access to the article, but you posted a link to it.

Comment: The proof is there in the article....

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, reading the actual article will cost $15 per month. https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/mathematics-magazine

Comment: @IvanHieno I clicked on the link from your first paragraph and the article appeared before my eyes. What happens when you click on it?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, I get an article by Matthew Baker from Georgia Institute of Technology, not the original article from Mathematics Magazine.

Comment: @IvanHieno And that article (which, by the way, is from Mathematics Magazine) by Matthew Baker contains the proof that you're after.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos, yes, that is the proof that I don't understand. I can't understand why it is a proof of anything. I can't find any Parry Mason moment in that proof.

Comment: The proof is essentially three steps. (1) If $S$ is countable, then Bob has a winning strategy. (This is Proposition 1 in the linked paper.) (2) If $S=[0,1]$, then Bob does not have a winning strategy (because Alice wins, no matter what either player does). (3) Therefore $[0,1]$ is not countable.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume $S$ is countable, and Bob always chooses $s_n$ on his $n$th move if possible, then eventually each element of $S$ can no longer be chosen, i.e. for all $n$ there exists $N$ such that if $m \geq N$ then $s_n \not \in (a_m,b_m)$. In fact one can be more explicit: $N=n$ is sufficient, because either $b_n=s_n$ or $s_n \not \in (a_{n-1},b_{n-1})$. On the other hand, $\alpha \in (a_m,b_m)$ for all $m$. Thus for all $n,s_n \neq \alpha$, so $\alpha \not \in S$.

On the other hand, if you assume $S=[0,1]$, then whatever $\alpha$ winds up being, Alice wins by definition, because $\alpha$ will always exist and will always be in $[0,1]$. So $[0,1]$ cannot be countable or it would contradict the previous case.

Really it is not so different from Cantor's proof when you think carefully. Each move where Bob actually does pick $s_n$, he is forcing $\alpha$ to be at least a little bit smaller than $s_n$, which rules out $\alpha$ actually being equal to $s_n$. This is similar to setting the $n$th digit in the expansion of $\alpha$ to be something other than the $n$th digit in the expansion of $s_n$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is proving a different proposition than Cantor.  Cantor proved the power set of the naturals is uncountable by constructing a subset that is not in any countable list.  This article proves that a dense linear order that satisfies the least upper bound property is uncountable.  It needs a dense linear order to be able to pick a number in any interval and needs the least upper bound property to claim the chosen numbers converge to something.